# First two indices of array in matrix being overwritten

Tags: c

I have a struct for a matrix defined as follows:

```
struct tunnelmap {
    size_t height;
    size_t width;
    int** matrix;
};
typedef struct tunnelmap TunnelMap;
```

And an initialization function as follows:

```
TunnelMap* createTunnelMap(size_t height, size_t width) {
    TunnelMap* pTunnelMap = malloc(sizeof(TunnelMap));
    pTunnelMap->height = height;
    pTunnelMap->width = width;
    pTunnelMap->matrix = malloc(height * sizeof(int));
    for (size_t row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        pTunnelMap->matrix[row] = malloc(width * sizeof(int));
        for (size_t column = 0; column < width; column++) {
            pTunnelMap->matrix[row][column] = 1;
        }
    }
    return pTunnelMap;
}
```

When I initialize a new matrix (i.e. the `tunnelmap` struct):

```
TunnelMap* tm = createTunnelMap(5, 7);
```

The first two elements of the first 'row' of the matrix seem to be garbled data, while the rest of the matrix appears to be in order:

```
printf("%d\n", tm->matrix[0][0]); // --> -1016700064
printf("%d\n", tm->matrix[0][1]); // --> 22063
printf("%d\n", tm->matrix[0][2]); // --> 1
printf("%d\n", tm->matrix[0][3]); // --> 1
printf("%d\n", tm->matrix[1][0]); // --> 1
printf("%d\n", tm->matrix[2][5]); // --> 1
printf("%d\n", tm->matrix[3][2]); // --> 1
printf("%d\n", tm->matrix[4][6]); // --> 1
```

I've properly iterated over the items of the matrix to ensure this is actually the case, and it definitely is. After each run of the program, the `[0][0]` cell and the `[0][1]` cell are both seemingly random integers, while all other cells are properly initialized to 1.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? My initial though was that somehow the `height` and `width` properties on the `tunnelmap` struct were somehow causing this issue, but I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: Here: `pTunnelMap->matrix = malloc(height * sizeof(int));`, you want to use `sizeof(int *)`, because each element of the array holds a pointer to int.

Comment: @MOehm Ah! Yes -- thank you! If you want to post that as an answer I would be more than happy to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Never forget the memory is addressable in a linear fashion, while the matrix access is two-dimensional. So when you are accessing `matrix[i][j]` you are actually accessing `matrix[i * width + j]`

Comment: @fvdalcin: That's not true. It would be true if you defined the array as `int matrix[M][N]`, but not when you create the matrix with dynamic allocation like it is done here: `matrix` is an array of pointers and each pointer holds the handle to an array of integers.